# i want to reset the seekbar to start position once the music is played and button showing "play"

Tags: java, android

i want to reset the seekbar to start position once the music is played and button showing "play"...The problem with the code is that the seek bar stays at the end position after its done playing the music and button still shows "pause"...

Here's my code

ekdanta.java

```
public class ekdanta extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable, View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
   TextView tv4;
   Button b9, b10,but19;
   int count = 0;
   MediaPlayer play;
   SeekBar seek_bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekdanta);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tv4.setTextSize((float)21.5);
    tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.thirteen)));
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    but19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
    but19.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void run() {
    int currentPosition= play.getCurrentPosition();
    int total = play.getDuration();
    while (play!=null && currentPosition<total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition= play.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        seek_bar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(but19)) {
        if (play == null) {
            play = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ekadanta);
            seek_bar.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (play.isPlaying()) {
            play.pause();
            but19.setText("Play");
        } else {
            play.start();
            but19.setText("Pause");
            seek_bar.setMax(play.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(play!=null){
        play.stop();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

public void increase(View inc) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
        tv4.setTextSize(25);
    } else if (count == 2) {
        tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count >= 3) {
        count = 3;
        tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
}

public void decrease(View dec) {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
        tv4.setTextSize((float)21.5);
        count = 0;
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        tv4.setTextSize(25);
    } else if (count == 2) {
        tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count == 3) {
        tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    try{
        if(play.isPlaying()||play!=null){
            if (fromUser)
                play.seekTo(progress);
        }
        else if(play==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            seek_bar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("seek bar",""+e);
        seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` has got `onCompletionListener()`, you can use that. Your code with handlers is not too reliable, it would be better to refactor it.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Comment: Slanecek could you please write some code and show....onCompletionListener() should come in the run()??

Comment: ok got it.....play.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                play.seekTo(0);
                but19.setText("Play");
            }